# How can we integrate pay fort payment gateway in our android application?

Tags: android-studio, payment-gateway, payfort

I want to integrate **pay fort payment gateway** in my android application. I searched for it on google, but could not find its solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay Fort API is only available in Ruby and PHP . Or if you want to integrate using your preferred language Pay Fort provides something called as RestSharp to connect to their API end points . They have provided documentation for payment gateway integration for Ruby and PHP for Android devices which you can find here at this link , and start coding https://docs.start.payfort.com/references/api/#introduction . They have provided start-up code hosted on GitHub on this link , which you can start to use and modify according to your needs . Let me know if that helped you :) .

Comment: @multi10ant is there any documentation of PayFort in iOS (Swift 2.2)? because I have found demo for Swift 3 but i require it in swift 2.2. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate PAYFORT mobile payment SDK you need to contact the support team and assign ur company as a merchant account on the FORT, to be able to integrate the SDK.

If you already have an account on the FORT, you can access the Mobile SDK files and the SDK integration guide directly. Otherwise having the file is useless.

Good luck.